# mysqli_prepare() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema local aqui pra loja onde eu trabalho e estou com o seguinte problema do título na hora de importar dados pro banco.

Seguem os códigos:

Classe Usuario

```
<?php

class Usuario {

    private $id;
    private $nome;
    private $tipo;
    private $login;
    private $senha;

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    function getTipo() {
        return $this->tipo;
    }

    function getLogin() {
        return $this->login;
    }

    function getSenha() {
        return $this->senha;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setNome($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    function setTipo($tipo) {
        $this->tipo = $tipo;
    }

    function setLogin($login) {
        $this->login = $login;
    }

    function setSenha($senha) {
        $this->senha = $senha;
    }

    public function cadastro ($nome, $login, $senha){

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (nome, login, senha) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param($stmt, $nome, $login, $senha);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

E aqui a conexão com o banco:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sysloja', '3306');
if (!$conn) {
   die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES \'utf8\'');

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função [mysqli_bind_param()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) pede dois argumentos o primeiro é uma string que define os tipos dos argumentos seguintes, como parecem ser strings utilize `s`

Mude:

```
public function cadastro ($nome, $login, $senha){
   $stmt->bind_param($stmt, $nome, $login, $senha);
```

Para:

```
public function cadastro ($con, $nome, $login, $senha){
   $stmt->bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $nome, $login, $senha);
```

Ou pode ainda simplificar um pouco as coisas e passar a própria conexão no construtor do de `Usuario` e deixar ela disponível para os demais métodos.

```
class Usuario {
   private $con;
   public function __construct($connection){
      $this->con = $connection;
   }
   //...demais métodos e propriedades
```

O método de cadastro a partir de agora deve usar a conexão que é um atribuito da classe/objeto ou seja para acessa-lá faça `$this->con`.

Com as alterações o método deve ficar dessa forma:

```
public function cadastro ($nome, $login, $senha){

    $stmt = $this->con->prepare('INSERT INTO usuario (nome, login, senha) VALUES (?,?,?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $nome, $login, $senha);
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        echo 'erro: '. $stmt->error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando parâmetro errado em 2 lugares.

---

Uma forma de corrigir:

Adicione a conexão como parâmetro e use-a na função `mysqli_prepare`:

```
public function cadastro ($nome, $login, $senha, $conn){

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, login, senha) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param($stmt, $nome, $login, $senha);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Para a consulta direta, também deve ser corrigido:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tabela';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

ou

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM tabela');
```

---

Documentação: [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php), [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php)